# Configure plugin directory for Hashicorp Vault on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to register a plugin for vault set up on GKE.

However, when i try and register the plugin i get an error message:
* could not set plugin, plugin directory is not configured

Does anyone know how i can set a plugin directory and add in the github repo for the plugin into this directory.

I believe this needs to be done within the vault config file but unsure on how this is achieved on GKE.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a similar setup as the one described in the [Using HashiCorp Vault on GKE](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/vault-on-gke) guide, you can set the `plugin_directory` in the `$VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG` environment variable for the `vault` container in the StatefulSet, like this:

```
$ kubectl edit statefulset vault
    spec:
    ...
      template:
      ...
        spec:
        ...
          containers:
          ...
          - args:
            ...
            env:
            ...
            - name: VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG
              value: |
                plugin_directory = "/etc/vault/plugins"
                ...
```

For adding the plugin binary into the `plugin_directory` for all pods, you can for instance use a [gcePersistentDisk volume](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/preexisting-pd) or just have the container download it on startup. For example, I could register this [vault-auth-plugin-example](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-auth-plugin-example) plugin with `$ vault write sys/plugins/catalog/example-auth-plugin sha_256=$SHA256 command="vault-auth-plugin-example"` after adding these `command` and `args` arrays into the `vault` StatefulSet:

```
$ kubectl edit statefulset vault
    spec:
    ...
      template:
      ...
        spec:
        ...
          containers:
          ...
          - args:
            ...
            name: vault
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args: ["-c", "(mkdir -vp /etc/vault/plugins && cd /etc/vault/plugins && wget -O- https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-auth-plugin-example/releases/download/v0.1.0/vault-auth-plugin-example_0.1.0_linux_amd64.tgz | tar xzf -) && docker-entrypoint.sh server"]
            ...
```